# How to use multiprocessing for a for loop? How to make a core run the loop from index n1 to n2 and the other core from index n2 to n3?

Tags: python, for-loop, multiprocessing, healpy

I have written a code to assign values of a 2D-gaussian to and empty HEALPix array. For this, I have made a 'for' loop in pixel indices. But the code seems to be taking a lot of time to give output. Can someone help me break this loop into several pieces so that they are processed simultaneously? Following is the part of code that I want to multiprocess.

```
def fn(nside):
    bar = ProgressBar(maxval = npix)
    bar.start()
    for i in range(0,npix):
        bar.update(i)
        for j in range(0,npix):
            hpxmap0[hp.ang2pix(nside, ma_theta[i], ma_phi[j])] = gaussian_2D(np.pi*(0.5) - ma_theta[i], ma_phi[j])
    bar.finish()
    return hpxmap0
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a wrapped function to run the loop over a given pixel range:

```
def fn_dist(nside, i_lo, i_hi, j_lo, j_hi):
    ...
    for i in range(i_lo, i_hi):
        for j in range(j_lo, j_hi):
            ...
```

Now, you need to fork off your processes over the desired ranges, dividing the matrix in slices of `i_step` and `j_step`:

```
for i_lo in range(0, npix, i_step):
    for j_lo in range(0, npix, j_step):
        # spawn a process for fn(nside, i_lo, i_lo+i_step, j_lo, j_lo+j_step)
```

Also look for ways to do block operations.  Could you write your own version of the `gaussian_2D` function to return a matrix of values over a given range?  I strongly suspect that most of your time currently is lost to the overhead of single-value function calls, rather than the data transfer.